# Use CakePHP applications layout in plugin

Tags: cakephp

I am writing a CakePHP plugin which does not have its own layout but utilises the layout of the application. I tried achieving this by just not creating the /Layout folder in the plugin BUT if i do that the controller crashes with a "Missing Route" error.

All tutorials are showing me how to use a plugin's Layout in my CakePHP application, but i want the opposite.

I am using CakePHP 3.X.

Comment: If plugin not have own layout and views files, then by default use parent application layout. But, you maybe has problem with your Router class inside plugin.

Comment: Unless you are overriding the default layout your plugin should be using the app's default one. It sounds like your problem is elsewhere. Check your error logs and trace the 'Missing Route' error you are getting.

Comment: Oh thanks, my issue was actually somewhere else. Working perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to create a view file for the controller method, then just try using line below in that controller method.

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```